# How to get the righttrim values of entire column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, patindex

[image]

How to fetch the values from the `Offset Group` column and `HedgeId` Column under following conditions?

1. The values fetched should contain the string mentioned in `SecurityGroupId` column
2. The values fetched from `Offset Group` column and `HedgeId` Column should only contain the remaining string which is towards the right of the string mentioned in `SecurityGroupId`.

Answer (score 1):

please use the query below,

```
select 
parsename(replace(OffsetGroup,SecurityGroupID,'.'),1) as [Offset Group],
parsename(replace(HedgeID,SecurityGroupID,'.'),1) as [HedgeID]
from @TableName
where OffsetGroup like '%'+SecurityGroupID+'%'
and HedgeID like '%'+SecurityGroupID +'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `Offset Group` and `HedgeID` values using `SecurityGroupID` matching your rows with `like` conditions and then use a CTE with an XML conversion to retrieve your data as columns:

```sql
declare  @tmp table(SecurityGroupID varchar(10), OffsetGroup nvarchar(50), HedgeID varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
 ('S1G', 'OG139099S1G36', 'HG139099S1G1')
,('S1G', 'OG139099S1G36', 'HG139099S1G2')
,('S1G', 'OG139099S1G36', 'HG139099S1G3')
,('S1G', 'OG139099S1G36', 'HG139099S1G4')
,('S1G', 'OG139099S1G36', 'HG139099S2G4')
,('S1G', 'OG139099S2G36', 'HG13909912G4')

;WITH CTEwithSplittedValues AS 
( 
    select 
         CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(OffsetGroup, SecurityGroupID,'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Offset_Group
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(HedgeID, SecurityGroupID,'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Hedge_ID
    from @tmp
    where OffsetGroup like '%' + SecurityGroupID + '%' 
          and HedgeID like '%' + SecurityGroupID + '%' 
)
SELECT 
Offset_Group.value(N'/x[2]','varchar(50)') AS [Offset Group] 
,Hedge_ID.value(N'/x[2]','varchar(50)') AS [HedgeID]

FROM CTEwithSplittedValues;
```

This is the final output:

[image]

The last two rows are not extracted because `SecurityGroupID` is not found in both `Offset Group` and `HedgeID`, but in only one of them.